# Android Remove First and Last <div> tag from html text using Jsoup

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I want to remove first and last div tag from the html text. i use jsoup library to parse the html text.i tried some thing which are shown in code.The html text which have more than one div tag or not be , but i want to remove just first and last div tag if available. please help me. thanks in advance.

```
 public String divremove(String html) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    for (Element e : doc.select("div")){
        if (e != null) {
            Log.e("LOG","link  >> " + e.text());
        }
    }
/*  Element link = doc.removeClass("div");
    if (link != null) 
    {
    }
    Integer in = doc.select("div").first().elementSiblingIndex();*/

    Element link = doc.select("div").first();
    Log.e("LOG","link  >> " + link);
    Element link2 = doc.select("div").last();
    Log.e("LOG","link2  >> " + link2.text());
    return html;//formatted
}
```

Comment: if you get this data in string than spit this data using div and add in Array and using loop you can remove first and last div.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example:

```
final String html = "<div>A</div><div>B</div><div>C</div><div>D</div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);


// (1) - Remove from html
doc.select("div").first().remove();
doc.select("div").last().remove();

System.out.println(doc.body());


// (2) - Remove from list
Elements divs = doc.select("div");
divs.remove(0);
divs.remove(divs.size()-1);

System.out.println(divs);
```

`(1)` removes the first and last tag from the html, so `doc` wont contain them anymore. If you just want to remove them from your selected div's, use `(2)` instead. This will keep it in your html (= `doc`), but it's removed from `divs`.